# What's the difference between these two python programs?

Tags: python

I am solving a algorithm problem on LeetCode (5th problem if you want to read the problem first
https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-palindromic-substring/).
I wrote a python program:

```
class Solution(object):
    def longestPalindrome(self, s):
        """
        :type s: str
        :rtype: str
        """
        l = 1
        if len(s) < 2:
            return s
        result = s[0]
        for end in range(1, len(s)):
            if end - (l + 1) >= 0 and s[end - (l + 1):end + 1] == s[end - (l + 1):end + 1][::-1]:
                l += 2
                result = s[end - (l + 1):end + 1]
                continue
            elif end - l >= 0 and s[end - l:end + 1] == s[end - l:end + 1][::-1]:
                l += 1
                result = s[end-l:end+1]
        return result
```

When I test it using '**abba**' as input: it outputs '**ba**'.
Then, I found a python solution in the discussion, the program looks like this:

```
class Solution:
    # @return a string
    def longestPalindrome(self, s):
        if len(s) == 0: return 0
        maxLen = 1
        start = 0
        for i in xrange(len(s)):
            if i - maxLen >= 1 and s[i - maxLen - 1:i + 1] == s[i - maxLen - 1:i + 1][::-1]:
                start = i - maxLen - 1
                maxLen += 2
                continue
            if i - maxLen >= 0 and s[i - maxLen:i + 1] == s[i - maxLen:i + 1][::-1]:
                start = i - maxLen
                maxLen += 1
        return s[start:start + maxLen]
```

When I test it using '**abba**' as input, it outputs '**abba**' correctly.
I am a pretty new beginner in python, so I always get confused by the matter of passing parameters in python. So, could anyone tell me why the two python programs get two different results?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add some prints and step through the code,  you will be able to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

You change `l` between where you determine there is a palindrome and where you use `l` to assign that palindrome to `result`.  In both places.